# Javascript substring does not extract the correct data

Tags: javascript, indexof, substr

I use javascript with `indexOf` and `substr` and I try to get 3 parts.

**Expected result**

Part1:

```
<p>Some text</p>

BEFORE
```

Part2:

```
<!-- KEYWORDS: one -->
```

Part3:

```
<p>Some more text</p>
```

**Real results**

Run the code below with the console log and you will see that the parts are all over the place.

```js
class Inside {
  getPos(selector, startsWith, endsWith) {
    const html = document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
    let data = {};
    data.pos = {};
    data.html = {};

    data.pos.start = html.indexOf(startsWith);
    data.pos.end = html.indexOf(endsWith, data.pos.start);
    data.pos.finish = html.length;

    data.html.before = html.substr(0, data.pos.start);
    data.html.match = html.substr(data.pos.start, data.pos.end);
    data.html.after = html.substr(data.pos.end, data.pos.finish);

    console.log(data.pos);
    console.log(data.html.before);
    console.log(data.html.match);
    console.log(data.html.after);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const InsideObj = new Inside();
  InsideObj.getPos('main', '<!-- KEYWORDS:', '-->');
});
```

```html
<main>
   <p>Some text</p>

   BEFORE
   <!-- KEYWORDS: one -->
   AFTER

    <p>Some more text</p>
  </main>
```

**Question**

I can't figure out why it does not add up. Is it `substr` or `indexOf`? Is it some kind of multibyte or encoding problem that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substr()` does not take two string positions, but rather one position and one length like this: `substr(startingPosition, subLength)`.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
let str = 'Hello Test';

let startPos = 3, endPos = 5; // We expect a string with 2 chars starting from the 3nd position

console.log(str.substr(startPos, endPos)); // WRONG! 
console.log(str.substr(startPos, endPos - startPos));
```

Here is your fixed code:
You need to subtract the starting position from your end position, to get the length between the two (like in the example above). Also, you need to take into account the length of the search parameter itself.

```js
class Inside {
  getPos(selector, startsWith, endsWith) {
    const html = document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
    let data = {};
    data.pos = {};
    data.html = {};

    data.pos.start = html.indexOf(startsWith);
    data.pos.end = html.indexOf(endsWith, data.pos.start);
    data.pos.finish = html.length;

    data.html.before = html.substr(0, data.pos.start);
    
    // From the start position to end - start plus the length of the string you searched
    data.html.match = html.substr(data.pos.start, data.pos.end - data.pos.start + endsWith.length);
    
    // From the end position + the length of the string you searched to finish - end
    data.html.after = html.substr(data.pos.end + endsWith.length, data.pos.finish - data.pos.end);

    console.log(data.pos);
    console.log(data.html.before);
    console.log(data.html.match);
    console.log(data.html.after);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const InsideObj = new Inside();
  InsideObj.getPos('main', '<!-- KEYWORDS:', '-->');
});
```

```html
<main>
   <p>Some text</p>

   BEFORE
   <!-- KEYWORDS: one -->
   AFTER

    <p>Some more text</p>
  </main>
```

Comment: Great answer! With that information, I've written a short utility function and added it as an additional answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @MauriceNino is the correct one.

Just as a compliment, I've used that information and made a short utility function out of it. It returns an object with three chunks, `before`, `after` and `match`.

```js
function getChunks(selector, strStart, strEnd) {
  const html = document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
  const start = html.indexOf(strStart);
  const end = html.indexOf(strEnd, start);

  if (start == -1 || end == -1) return;

  return {
    before: html.substr(0, start),
    match: html.substr(start, end - start + strEnd.length),
    after: html.substr(end + strEnd.length, html.length - end)
  };
}

let chunks = getChunks('main', '<!-- KEYWORDS:', '-->');
console.log(chunks);
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Some text

  BEFORE
  <!-- KEYWORDS: one -->
  AFTER

  <p>Some more text</p>
</main>
```